# In Apps Script, where and how to add page format detail when exporting a pdf?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

New to apps scripts so this is probably a very basic question, more familiar with visual basic from a long time ago. I have put together a script that does everything I want with one exception. It exports a PDF from a google sheet to the appropriate google drive folder I have created and also emails me a copy. Only thing is the formatting of the exported PDF. It is off center and I don't know where in the script to add the relevant margin control, fit to page, portrait vs landscape.

I looked at various examples of PDF export scripts that had page set up control in them and tried to incorporate them into my existing script, but not being familiar enough with the structure, I wasn't getting proper results and was often generating an error in the script running properly at all. So I removed all of those attempts and restored the code that was functioning (just without the exported PDF looking how I want). I will post the current code here - hope this is the appropriate place - just signed up for this site. And thanks in advance for any help.

```
function exportSheet() { 

  var sheetName2 = 'PDF for Export'   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vYR5vtHkIkVDZtbSxsocOYEF1DNkaOPnc47irOpE_Rc')
  var namen = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vYR5vtHkIkVDZtbSxsocOYEF1DNkaOPnc47irOpE_Rc').getRange("PDF Builder!E2").getValues();
  var number = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vYR5vtHkIkVDZtbSxsocOYEF1DNkaOPnc47irOpE_Rc').getRange("PDF Builder!E1").getValues();
  var nextnumber = +number + 1
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName2) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
  newFile.setName(namen);
  newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('1I8whlpP1f56SufXEp5eKBTLzIBnA6Fau')); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail('daryn@cineviewstudiosfl.com','NEW QUOTE','NEW QUOTE',
  {attachments: [newFile]});

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('PDF Builder!E1').setValue(nextnumber);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified code and experiment on the PDF parameters. One note: for privacy reasons, no need to include the ID of your doc or gDrive folder when you share your code.

Hope this helps.

```
function exportSheet() { 

  var sheetName2 = 'PDF for Export'   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var namen = ss.getRange("PDF Builder!E2").getValues();
  var number = ss.getRange("PDF Builder!E1").getValues();
  var nextnumber = +number + 1
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName2) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    }
  }

  var PDF4Export = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName2);
  
  // Base URL of your export file
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());
  
  // Specify PDF export parameters
    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
         + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
         + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
         + '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
         + '&top_margin=0.25'              
         + '&bottom_margin=0.25'          
         + '&left_margin=0.25'             
         + '&right_margin=0.25' 
         + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
         + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=true' // hide page numbers and gridlines
         + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
         + '&gid='; //the ID of the sheet to be exported is appended here. See response variable

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + PDF4Export.getSheetId(), {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            muteHttpExceptions: true
        });
  
  //just get the exported file, not the entire worksheet
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob());
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
  newFile.setName(namen);
  newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('your_gDrive_folder_id_here')); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail('john.doe@gmail.com','TEST','TEST',
  {attachments: [newFile]});

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('PDF Builder!E1').setValue(nextnumber);

}
```