# Great PDF from single worksheet tab in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am working on a project where I am using Google Sheets to create a new sheet for payroll each time I hit "run payroll" the issue now is I want it to have it become a PDF and go into a specific folder and then email it out.

I found the first part then tried to do it with zapier but its not working as its creating the entire sheet as a PDF not the new one.

```
// Add menu items.
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Run Payroll', functionName: 'runPayroll'},
    {name: 'Delete Paystub', functionName: 'deletePayroll'}, 
    {name: 'Rebuild YTD from Stubs', functionName: 'rebuildYTD'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Payroll', menuItems);
}

function runPayroll() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Template');
  
  // Validate weekly input
  if(!validateInput()) {
    return;
  }
    
  // Create new sheet for pay date
  var sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(getNamedValue('TempPayDate'), "PST", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var paystubSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (paystubSheet) {
    // we already have a paystub for this date. remove that stub's values from YTD before we create a new one.
    removePayrollFromYTD(paystubSheet);
    paystubSheet.clear();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // ran into a race issue here with YTD not getting updated fast enough for the new stub creation -- flush() seems to fix it
  } else {
    paystubSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName, spreadsheet.getNumSheets());
  }  

  // Copy pay data from Template to new sheet 
  var dataRange = templateSheet.getRange(1, 1, 45, 6);
  dataRange.copyValuesToRange(paystubSheet, 1, 6, 1, 45);
  dataRange.copyFormatToRange(paystubSheet, 1, 6, 1, 45);
  paystubSheet.setRowHeight(1, 10);
  paystubSheet.setRowHeight(2, 10);
  paystubSheet.setRowHeight(43, 10);
  paystubSheet.setRowHeight(44, 10);
    
  // Update YTD sheet. Grab current values from the template before we clean it up
  updateYTDFromCurrent();
    
  // Reset template data
  cleanup();
  
  // Activate new paystub and pre-set selection for printing
  paystubSheet.activate();
  paystubSheet.setActiveSelection(paystubSheet.getRange(1, 1, 45, 6));

//  Logger.log(sheetName);
//  dumpLog();
}

function validateInput() {
  // hours
  var hrsReg = getNamedValue('TempHoursReg');
  var hrsOT = getNamedValue('TempHoursOT');
  if(hrsReg + hrsOT <= 0) {
    Browser.msgBox('Error', 'Work harder. Enter some hours.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return 0;
  }

  // taxes
  var taxFed = getNamedValue('TempFedTax');
  var taxCa = getNamedValue('TempCaTax');
  if(taxFed <= 0 || taxCa <= 0) {
    Browser.msgBox('Error', 'Pay your fair share. Enter some taxes.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return 0;
  }
    
  // dates
  // very basic sanity on pay period
  var begin = getNamedValue('TempPeriodBegin');
  var end = getNamedValue('TempPeriodEnd');
  if(end < begin) {
    Browser.msgBox('Error', 'Pay period looks funky.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return 0;
  }

  // warn on duplicate payroll
  var payDate = getNamedValue('TempPayDate');
  var sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(payDate, "PST", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var paystubSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (paystubSheet) {
    var resp = Browser.msgBox('Do Over?', 'You already have a paycheck for this date -- are you sure you want to overwrite it?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if(resp == 'no') {
       return 0;
    }
  }
  
  return 1;
}

function deletePayroll() {
  // prompt for the date 
  var strDel = Browser.inputBox('Delete Payroll', 'Please enter the date of the paystub to remove (mm/dd/yyyy):', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (strDel == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }

  // search for sheet and confirm deletion
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var deleteSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(strDel);
  if(deleteSheet) {
    var resp = Browser.msgBox('Are you sure?', Utilities.formatString("Located the payroll for %s -- continue with deletion?", strDel), Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if(resp == 'no') {
       return;
    }
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox('Error', Utilities.formatString("Couldn't find a paystub for %s. Nothing to delete. Hint: make sure you are using the form '01/09/2017' rather than '1/9/17'.", strDel), Browser.Buttons.OK);
    //todo: make this friendier
    return;
  }
  
  // Subtract from YTD sheet
  removePayrollFromYTD(deleteSheet);
  
  // Delete tab and return to template
  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(deleteSheet);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Template').activate();
  
  // todo: is it possible to trap the Delete Sheet action from UI and trigger this function? or at least ask if we should adjust YTD before deleting
}

function rebuildYTD() {
  // todo: 
  // copy current YTD to backup column or sheet
  // zero out current YTD values
  // cycle through all paystubs to sum new values
  Browser.msgBox('Payroll', "Haven't gotten around to this feature yet...", Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

function updateYTDFromCurrent() {
  incrementNamedValue('YTDFedTax', getNamedValue('CurFedTax'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDSocSec', getNamedValue('CurSocSec'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDMedicare', getNamedValue('CurMedicare'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDCaTax', getNamedValue('CurCaTax'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDCaSdi', getNamedValue('CurCaSdi'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDWagesReg', getNamedValue('CurWagesReg'));
  incrementNamedValue('YTDWagesOT', getNamedValue('CurWagesOT'));
}

function cleanup() {
  clearNamedValue('TempHoursReg');
  clearNamedValue('TempHoursOT');
  clearNamedValue('TempFedTax');
  clearNamedValue('TempCaTax');
/*  
  clearNamedValue('TempPeriodBegin');
  clearNamedValue('TempPeriodEnd');
  clearNamedValue('TempPayDate');
*/
}

function getNamedValue(valueName) {
  var nr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(valueName);
  return nr.getValue();
}

function incrementNamedValue(valueName, valueToAdd) {
  var nr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(valueName);
  nr.setValue(nr.getValue() + valueToAdd);
}

function clearNamedValue(valueName) {
  var nr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(valueName);
  if(nr) {
    nr.clearContent();
  }
}

function removePayrollFromYTD(payrollSheet) {
  // note: this will be fragile, we don't have named ranges for the individual payroll sheets so it's using specific cell IDs instead
  var wagesReg = payrollSheet.getRange('E30');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDWagesReg', -wagesReg.getValue());
  
  var wagesOT = payrollSheet.getRange('E31');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDWagesOT', -wagesOT.getValue());
  
  var fedTax = payrollSheet.getRange('E38');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDFedTax', -fedTax.getValue());

  var caTax = payrollSheet.getRange('E41');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDCaTax', -caTax.getValue());

  var caSdi = payrollSheet.getRange('E42');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDCaSdi', -caSdi.getValue());

  var socSec = payrollSheet.getRange('E39');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDSocSec', -socSec.getValue());

  var medicare = payrollSheet.getRange('E40');
  incrementNamedValue('YTDMedicare', -medicare.getValue());
}

function dumpLog() {
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('devlog');
  if(!logSheet) {
    logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet('devlog', 0); 
  }

  var logData = Logger.getLog();
  var a1 = logSheet.getRange(1,1);
  a1.setValue(logData);
}
```

Comment: Here's a similar post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781031/send-active-sheet-as-pdf-to-email-listed-in-cell) that may help you. If you still face an issue, feel free to post here what you've come up with.

Comment: @TomR I'm not looking for it to do the email portion with the code to be honest. I'm just looking to add the export to PDF of the newly created sheet based on the script above to a specific folder

I've tested a couple things but can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Got it, sorry for the confusion. Please check Daryn's original code in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853837/in-apps-script-where-and-how-to-add-page-format-detail-when-exporting-a-pdf/74917234#74917234) to see how he exports a specific sheet into a specific folder as PDF. The idea is to loop through all the sheets and hide them - except the one to be exported - before converting it into PDF. And if you are interested to format the PDF, check out my answer on the same post. Hope it helps.